# Following users who tweets a specific hashtag with tweepy for python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

can some one show me the code of how can I follow all users who tweet about a specific hashtag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) and start with a search  [example](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/examples/search_results.py) wich you can modify to suit your needs .

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

# Requires Authentication as of Twitter API v1.1
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
try:
    search_results = twitter.search(q='#python', count=50)
except TwythonError as e:
    print e

for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
    print tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
```